# Error 38824 : A CREATE OR REPLACE Command May not Change the EDITIONABLE Property of an Existing Object

Tags: oracle

we are implementing a unit test system of our database production object like package, procedure, trigger & co. To do so, we have a container which create a database from https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase .
Then we execute scripts which are creating schema, users, grant some privileges, create good tablespaces... Then we use Data Pump Oracle to expdp and impdp the schema. These steps are successful.

The problem appear when we try to exec test on our Procedures and Packages. They are not find in schema due to compilation error "ORA-38824 : A CREATE OR REPLACE Command May not Change the EDITIONABLE Property of an Existing Object".

But if we drop the procedure tested, then recreate it, the error does not appear anymore. Things is we do not want to manually drop & re create the procedure.

the only difference between our environment & the container database is that when we create a procedure/package from scratch, Editionable parameter in object detail are at 'N' in container when it is at 'Y' in our env.

It seems that Editionable parameter for objects has to be set at Database level.
But the question is where can it be set ?

We tried to 'ALTER USER X ENABLE EDITIONS;' without success since it is causing 'ORA-38813: editions not supported for schema X'.

Is Impdp & Expdp causing trouble ?

We tried using 'source_edition' & 'target_edition' for our expdp impdp process.
We are clearly missing something or doing something wrong but we are not able to find what.

I have searched on internet, but not too much people have been facing this issue..

Could you please provide us help?

Thanks in advance.
Vincent.

Comment: Do you use editions in your environment and are you packagers/functions/procedures editioned? If so the container database environment and your actual environment are both the same from a configuration stand point - e.g if you are using editions then do the same for the container database? I don't understand all details but from what I understood these are a few pointers.

Comment: No we do not use edition, but from a configuration stand point we are able to use edition and both environment have the same Oracle version. (12C release 2)

Comment: If you do not use editions then is it possible to keep the configuration exactly same  in the two environments? Then I would guess that the issue would get resolved.

Comment: We checked multiple time the configuration and it's the same.

Comment: I had the same problem and spent a lot of time to solve it. In the script where I created the user was the first statement `alter session set "_oracle_script"=true;`. After I removed that line, the error was gone.

Comment: Ok nice to have an answer, but since then we found another solution using SQLPlus, which use directly our git repository. this use case was more relevant for our use case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I went through this recently, and analyzing it we would not use the `EDITIONABLE` functionality, so I ran the command below, leaving the `NONEDITIONABLE` objects, because that way the objects are replaced. And in the `DBA_OBJECTS` table, the `EDITIONABLE` column is `N`, so when it is time to do the imp, there is no problem.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
  TYPE t_string_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  vcursor      t_cursor;
  varraystring t_string_array;
  vstring      VARCHAR2(500);
  i            BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  OPEN vcursor FOR
    select 'ALTER ' || do.object_type || ' ' || do.owner || '.' || do.object_name || ' NONEDITIONABLE'
      from DBA_OBJECTS do
     where do.editionable = 'Y'
       and do.owner NOT IN('QS_CB','DIP','PERFSTAT','QS_ADM','PM','SH','HR','OE','ODM_MTR','WKPROXY','ANONYMOUS','OWNER','SYS','SYSTEM','SCOTT','SYSMAN','XDB','DBSNMP','EXFSYS','OLAPSYS','MDSYS','WMSYS','WKSYS','DMSYS','ODM','EXFSYS','CTXSYS','LBACSYS','ORDPLUGINS','SQLTXPLAIN','OUTLN','TSMSYS','XS$NULL','TOAD','STREAM','SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN','SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN','SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','QS','QS_CBADM','QS_CS','QS_ES','QS_OS','QS_WS','PA_AWR_USER','OWBSYS_AUDIT','OWBSYS','ORDSYS','ORDDATA','ORACLE_OCM','SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN_USR','SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN_USR','MGMT_VIEW','MDDATA','FLOWS_FILES','FLASHBACK','AWRUSER','APPQOSSYS','APEX_PUBLIC_USER','DVSYS')
       and do.object_type IN ('FUNCTION','LIBRARY','PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE','PROCEDURE','TRIGGER','TYPE','TYPE BODY','SYNONYM','VIEW');
  LOOP
    FETCH vcursor BULK COLLECT
      INTO varraystring;
    EXIT WHEN varraystring.count = 0;
    FOR i IN varraystring.first .. varraystring.last LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varraystring(i);
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN vcursor%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE vcursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked the Oracle Support website (should  have done this earlier) and this error is related to a bug in 12c. For example in one such document ([Meta Link Document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=5uz8vie4j_9&_afrLoop=560766370914473)) it is said as follows. So please refer this issue to Oracle by raising an SR and most likely they will come back with a suggestion for an Oracle version upgrade:

Please apply the merge patch Bug 27314007 : MERGE REQUEST ON TOP OF 12.2.0.1.0 FOR BUGS 25557064 26645487

Using these steps for the upgrade:

1. Stop the current DBUA session.
2. Download and apply the patch to 12.2 Oracle home.
3. Restore the 12.1 database.
4. Re-run the upgrade from 12.1 to 12.2.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try and refer this issue to Oracle, and try these steps as you said. I will inform you when I get there.

Comment: All the best...do get back on what Oracle comes back with. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I could not patch my image Oracle before because my dba was overbooked. We just now managed to patch it. Unfortunatly, the error is still here. We are going to try to import our schema not from EXPDP IMPDP, just simply sqlplus our sql file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh Ok. Sorry to know.  Hope the other workaround that you have works out!

Comment: Hello, forgot to respond on this topic. the real problem (editionable ect) was because we were using impdp and expdp. The workaround was to use a sqlplus cli. We customize a scripts that take all our objects and insert them into DB. For the patch, we used the 'applypatch' of the git repo from which I built my image. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big issue, just a grant access issue.
Run this query from SYS/Admin user

GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO ;

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  for x in (
    select 'ALTER ' || OBJECT_TYPE || ' ' || OBJECT_NAME || ' NONEDITIONABLE' as COMANDO
    from USER_OBJECTS
       and OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','LIBRARY','PACKAGE BODY','PACKAGE','PROCEDURE','TRIGGER','TYPE','TYPE BODY','SYNONYM','VIEW')
 ) loop
    execute immediate x.COMANDO;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).