# Get error: ORA-38824 during "create or replace" command

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have similar issue - when i try execute (compile package) "CREATE OR REPLACE" at a package body (just changes PLSQL code) then i have error:

> Error: ORA-38824: Команда CREATE OR REPLACE не может изменить свойство
>   EDITIONABLE существующего объекта.
>   *(A CREATE OR REPLACE Command May not Change the EDITIONABLE Property of an Existing Object")*

It is server version (result of `select * from v$version;`):

1. Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
2. PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
3. CORE    12.2.0.1.0  Production
4. TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
5. NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218477/error-38824-a-create-or-replace-command-may-not-change-the-editionable-propert) post, but they not have pure answer.

I then search some info about this error-code:[here](https://www.oraexcel.com/oracle-12cR1-ORA-38824), but i don't know, what is mean
"switch the EDITIONABLE property in the REPLACE statement"

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The default is `editionable`, so that’s how most packages are getting created if you’re not specifying anything. If you then try to recreate a package as `create or replace noneditionable package xyz` you’ll get ORA-38824. Or perhaps it was created noneditionable, and so the default `create or replace` now counts as an attempt to change it. You can find the current setting in `user_objects`.

Comment: This object have `EDITIONABLE` propherty as Y (enable) afore, but i now recreate this package as "create or replace editionable..." and it is working. But i still do not understand why it does not recreate without "editionable" (it is default behavior...)

Comment: UPD: and for another database (production copy) package recreate without this HINT..

Comment: Are you saying you get ORA-38824 for a standard `create or replace package` when the existing version is editionable? Is there any test case that reproduces this? Is there any noneditionable PL/SQL anywhere? Maybe tracing the session would help.

Comment: "Are you saying you get ORA-38824 for a standard create or replace package when the existing version is editionable?" - yes so. Now i not have a test for this.

Comment: @СергейSer, did you solve your issue ? 
I'm also facing the same problem, and don't have a clue on how to fix this :(

Comment: Yes. but i forgot my solution..just try delete and after recreate your procedure